# Suppose $f(x,y)=c(x^{m}+y^{n})-dx^{a}y^{b}+sin(x+y^{2})$, show that f is greater than

Tags: inequality

Suppose $f(x,y)=c(x^{m}+y^{n})-dx^{a}y^{b}+\sin(x+y^{2})$, where m,n are positive even integers, a,b are positive integers, c,d are positive real numbers and $\frac{a}{m}+\frac{b}{n}<1$. Show that there is a number C such that $f(x,y)\geq \frac{c}{2}(x^{m}+y^{n})-C $ for all x,y. 
Could any one give me some hint to this question? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since
$$\sin{(x+y^2)}\ge -1$$
since
$$\dfrac{a}{m}+\dfrac{b}{n}<1$$
note $a,b,m,n$ are postive numbers,then we choose $a,b,m,n$ such
$$x^{\frac{m}{2}-a}y^{\frac{n}{2}-b}>\dfrac{d}{c}$$
$$\Longrightarrow cx^{\frac{m}{2}}y^{\frac{n}{2}}>d\cdot x^ay^b$$
so use AM-GM inequality we have $$dx^ay^b<cx^{\frac{m}{2}}y^{\frac{n}{2}}\le \dfrac{c}{2}(x^m+y^n)$$
so there exsit constant $C$ such
$$f(x,y)\ge c(x^m+y^n)-dx^ay^b-1\ge \dfrac{c}{2}(x^m+y^n)-C$$